# Wicket page refreshing when making ajax request

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

My wicket application has 2 pages named page A and page B

Page B has 2 AjaxTabbedPanel tabs.

Click an ajax link in page A, user will navigate to the second tab of page B by this code:

```
setResponsePage(new PageB(new PageBModel()));
```

Obviously It will navigate to the first tab and I am checking some condition to keep navigating to the second tab by this code:

```
if (condition) {
    ajaxTab.setSelectedTab(1);
} else {
    ajaxTab.setSelectedTab(0);
}
```

And making ajax request in the second tab of Page B (clicking to the button e.g.), It will return to the first tab and the page id has been changed.

I noticed that if wicket aware stale page, it will reload it. For example:

1. Open Page A => /pageA/?0
2. Open Page B in new browser tab => /pageB/?1
3. Comeback to Page A and try to manipulate. Wicket aware this page A is stale, let's reload it => Whole Page A has been reloaded

But in my case, It's not really stale page because I manipulate it in the same browser tab.
Do you have any idea to fix this issue? And what is the root cause here made the page switch back to the first tab?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is not very clear - you talk about `tabs` (Wicket AjaxTabbedPanel) but I have the feeling you also mean browser tabs at some points. Please clarify whether you use different browser tabs at any point.

Comment: Edited! Sorry for confusing you

Comment: I have no idea what is the reason, but you could debug it locally by putting a breakpoint at Wicket Page#dirty() method and see why it is being called for PageA. From your description it is not clear how you return to PageA

Comment: Okay. I will debug and give u the result as soon as possibile

Comment: I comeback to page A by switching browser tab

Comment: It just my explaination how wicket deal with stale page, maybe it not connect to my issue

Comment: Btw I am very appreciate your help

Comment: Hi again @martin-g,
I found that setResponsePage without page parameters is problem.
I switch to use it with page parameters and it works properly.
I don't know exactly why this setResponsePage causing this issue

Comment: I'm glad it works!